# SharePoint Lists - Can you Lookup a Lookup column value?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, lookup-column

Hear me out on this one, I know it sounds silly but I am looking for a work around to this issue. We know that building a database would be the best solution, but that is a project for the future at this point in time. A database would be a lot easier to make changes to, however, this is what we have for now.

I did search the forum but the only post was from 10 years ago which is so far out of date, it wasn't worth reading. We are using SharePoint Online.

We have a SharePoint List that looks like this:

[image: SharePoint List Example]

The first Lookup value is Suburb - we use this to prevent misspellings and incorrectly allocated regions for reporting purposes. Once the suburb value is selected, it uses a lookup from the suburb source list to fill in a range of other fields.

The issue we have is that Lookup uses a massive list that has values that often change. We would like to separate out those two pieces of information into a separate list that will be much easier to manage and update. For example, we have thousands of suburbs and only a handful of regions and region managers. Therefore the regions and region managers are going to be put on a separate list to make it easier to update those changes going forward.

As I have discovered, you cannot create a calculated column that refers to a value in a lookup column, nor can you create a lookup that looks up the value in your current list. Can this only be done with JSON formatting?

For example, I cannot use the Suburb Field or the Suburb: LGA field as a value to create another lookup for just the region and region managers. I would appreciate any advice. If JSON formatting is the only solution, that is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my knowledge, you cannot create a calculated column that refers to a value in a lookup column, nor can you create a lookup that looks up the value in your current list. The JSON format you said should be the only solution.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I sincerely appreciate it. I will come up with another solution.